# Switching between pthreads on a timer

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I want to make two pthreads in a c++ program using a single processor. Thread1 will be endlessly running but needs to be interrupted every 5 microseconds to allow thread2 to do one iteration of a while loop before switching back to thread1. I know how to make the pthreads and whatnot, but I can't figure out how to make the switching between threads based on a timer occur. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want the two threads to run simultaneously then you should not use two threads. The second thread can be used as a function to be called from the first thread each 5 micro seconds.

Comment: I'm fairly new to pthreads so my understanding is probably skewed. To go along with what you said, what would be the easiest way to call a function within a thread every 5 micro seconds?

Comment: A high-priority hardware timer interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with what you want is the scale of the time interval for the interrupts. Usual OS do not switch threads that often, the normal rate lays in milliseconds scale. To achieve 5 microseconds intervals you need either

- Real-time OS with low-cost high-precision interrupts or write your own kernel module for the same purpose.
- Proactively schedule the threads. I.e. more or less similar to what Samer suggested.

I'm not familiar with RtOS or drivers. And I doubt you might need this very specialized solution. As for the second approach..

## pthreads

You can still do it with pthreads but make sure the thread1 calls OS at least every 5 microseconds to give the OS a chance to reschedule it to thread2. And you'd need to assign higher priority for thread2 or set different scheduling policy like Round-Robin instead of Fair Scheduling: [see here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getschedparam.3.html).

However, this threads approach will suffer from significant overheads for context switches: assuming [roughly 1300 ns per context switch](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html), and that you need 2 switches per 5 microseconds, it leads to about **50% time of overheads**!

## coroutines

Another approach could be user-level threads ([coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/overview.html)/[fibers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661(v=vs.85).aspx)) scheduling. It has significantly less overheads and enables thread2 to be written as a loop which sleeps periodically instead of exiting its function completely. Anyway, it also requires thread1 to take care of having checkpoints with the rate sufficient to allow switches every 5 microseconds.

## function

And finally, if the thread2 can be easily implemented as function having a state in order to handle the loop, it is the best choice from both overheads and complexity points of view.